# SAP Sales Order Text Extraction to Excel

Tags: excel, sap-gui, vba

For years I worked with an ERP system that I could reach every corner of and get data out of very easily, but we have now moved to a global SAP system and with a much lower level of access things are not as easy.
I have a specific requirement to extract the data from some of the sales order item text fields; because these are encrypted and because I am limited to SQVI, this can't be done directly.
I tried recording a script to extract the data using transaction VA03 and found as everyone else has that the vital parts of saving as a local file aren't recorded.  I found a very useful post in the SAP archived discussions, https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3240622 in which this very problem was addressed, and managed to get header text saved into Excel by making some trivial changes to suit our configuration.

```html
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'


If Not IsObject(sap) Then

   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")

   Set sap = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine

End If

If Not IsObject(Connection) Then

   Set Connection = sap.Children(0)

End If

If Not IsObject(session) Then

   Set session = Connection.Children(0)

End If

If IsObject(WScript) Then

   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"

   WScript.ConnectObject sap, "on"

End If

session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 167, 31, False

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nva03"

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VBELN").Text = "nnnnnn"

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/btnBT_HEAD").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\09").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\09/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectItem "Z005", "Column1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\09/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").ensureVisibleHorizontalItem "Z005", "Column1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\09/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").doubleClickItem "Z005", "Column1"

Cells(1, 1) = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\08/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").Text

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
End Sub
```

This works, (the order number has been suppressed as nnnnnn in the highly unlikely event that someone might recognise it) and I was able to get data from other fields by adding lines, but when I try to do the same kind of thing for item text with the variation below

```html
ub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'


If Not IsObject(sap) Then

   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")

   Set sap = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine

End If

If Not IsObject(Connection) Then

   Set Connection = sap.Children(0)

End If

If Not IsObject(session) Then

   Set session = Connection.Children(0)

End If

If IsObject(WScript) Then

   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"

   WScript.ConnectObject sap, "on"

End If

session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 167, 31, False

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nva03"

session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VBELN").Text = "nnnnnn"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4400/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/subSUBSCREEN_BUTTONS:SAPMV45A:4050/btnBT_POPO").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtRV45A-POSNR").Text = "351"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtRV45A-POSNR").caretPosition = 3
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4400/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/subSUBSCREEN_BUTTONS:SAPMV45A:4050/btnBT_PKON").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\09").Select
' Texts is 9th tab - this leaves cursor on first text line, next line moves to Customer tags, but doesn't show content, which only shows on doubleClickItem "Z102" line
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\09/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").selectItem "Z102", "Column1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\09/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").ensureVisibleHorizontalItem "Z102", "Column1"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\09/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").doubleClickItem "Z102", "Column1"

Cells(1, 1) = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\09/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").Text


session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
End Sub
```

This brings up the the required fields on the SAP screen but then throws up an error, "Run-time error '619' The control could not be found be id."

I clearly don't understand all that is going on - can someone help me, please?

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not have access to transaction VA03. But if all commands were actually recorded by the script recorder, then I can imagine that the data is not ready when they are queried. And so perhaps a little break might be the solution.

for example:

```
...
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\09/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").doubleClickItem "Z102", "Column1"
waitTill = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
While Now() < waitTill
  DoEvents
Wend

Cells(1, 1) = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\09/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4152/subSUBSCREEN_TEXT:SAPLV70T:2100/cntlSPLITTER_CONTAINER/shellcont/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").Text
...
```

Regards,
ScriptMan

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I still get the same result.  Strictly all the commands were not recorded directly by the recorder, as that doesn't record the vital saving to the external application, rather I took the published code for copying the header text and substituted the recorded code for displaying the item text for that which showed the header text, assuming, or hoping that the next line would copy the new source text in the same way as it had the header text.

Comment: Can you publish a screen shot please?

Comment: But you could also record a script that writes a new text in the container. The recording will then be stopped and you will not save the new text of course. In the script itself you have the command what you could use then.

Comment: That is a  great idea - thank you!  I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: I have a script which puts text into the relevant place, but how do I show it?  It is too big to be a comment.

Comment: I did not ask a question here. But I would imagine that you can edit the question or you can give yourself an answer with the recorded script.